# multiple integral finding limit integration

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, area, multiple-integral

question : 
$\iint_D \ln(x^2 + y^2)dxdy$ ,

 domain : $4\le x^2+y^2 \le 9$ 
im having hard times to find the limit for integration  because it is in polar coordinates, i got that $2 \le r\le 3$ but i dont know how to find the $\theta$ limit. 
and also i dont know the graph actually, is it the same as logarithm graph? is it better to draw the graph? is there another way beside drawing the graph? thanks!

Comment: You can take $0 \le \theta \le  2 \pi$.

Comment: @olivieroloa thankyou but can you explain to me how to get it??

Comment: @Vixf Try drawing the equations $r=2$ and $r=3$ in polar. There is no restriction on $\theta$ so your domain goes "all the way around" the polar origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You make the change of variables: 
$$x=r\cos{\theta},y=r\sin{\theta}.$$
Hence: 
$$4\le x^2+y^2 \le 9 \Rightarrow 2^2\le r^2\le 3^2 \Rightarrow 2\le r\le 3.$$
The domain is the region between the cocentric circles with the center at the origin and the radii $2$ and $3$, therefore:
$$0\le \theta \le 2\pi.$$
Note: If the domain was $4\le x^2+y^2\le 9, x\ge 0, y\ge 0$, then it would be the region between the concentric circles with the center at the origin and the radii $2$ and $3$ that lies in the first quadrant, implying $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.

> The formula of double integration in polar coordinates is:
>   $$\iint_{D} f(x,y)dxdy = \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \int_{r_1}^{r_2}f(r\cos{\theta},r\sin{\theta})\cdot Jdrd{\theta},$$
>   where $J$ is the Jacobian:
>   $$J=\begin{vmatrix}
>         x_r & x_{\theta} \\
>         y_r & y_{\theta} \\
>         \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}
>         \cos{\theta} & -r\sin{\theta} \\
>         \sin{\theta} & r\cos{\theta} \\
>         \end{vmatrix} = r.$$

Hence the integral:
$$\iint_{4\le x^2+y^2\le 9} \ln(x^2+y^2)dxdy =\int_0^{2\pi} \int_2^3 \ln{r^2}\cdot rdrd{\theta}=$$
$$\left(\int_0^{2\pi}d{\theta}\right) \left(\int_2^3 \underbrace{\ln{r}}_{u} \cdot \underbrace{2rdr}_{dv}\right)=(2\pi)\left(\ln r \cdot r^2 \bigg{|}_2^3-\int_2^3 r^2\cdot \frac1r dr\right)=$$
$$(2\pi)\left(9\ln 3-4\ln 2-\frac52 \right)\approx 28.996.$$

Comment: thanks i think i understand the domain, but for the integral $ \int_2^3 \ln{r}\cdot 2rdr$, how can you simplify like this?, i got $ln r^2\cdot \frac{1}{2} r^2- \frac{1}{2}r^2$

Comment: it is the integration by parts - the method of calculating integrals with non-simple integrand function.

Comment: yeah i know i use integral by part $u= ln (r^2)$ and $r dr = dv$, how can you make it like this $\int_2^3 \ln{r}\cdot 2rdr$

Comment: oh, it is the property of logarithm: $\ln r^2=2\ln r, 2\le r\le 3$

Comment: ok thanks!! and also if it is $x \geq 0$ and circle, the domain will be $0\le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: If $x\ge 0$ and the ring, then $-\pi/2 \le \theta \le \pi/2$. If $x\ge 0, y\ge 0$ and the ring, then $0\le \theta \le \pi/2$. You are welcome. Good luck.

Comment: sorry to ask again! what if the domain is $0 \le  y \le x$ and circle $x^2+y^2 \le 1$? is this become $0 \le y \le r cos \theta$?

Comment: You should change both $x$ and $y$ to polar coordinates. You can draw the domain and see $0\le r\le 1$ and $0\le \theta \le \pi/4$.

Comment: i try to draw $y=x$ ,so where $\pi/4$ when $rsin \theta \le r cos\theta$? and also  If $≥0,y≥0 $ and the ring, then$0\le \theta \le \pi/2$ is actually 1/4 of circle in first quadrant?

Comment: Yes, both correct. Indeed, in the first case: $0\le y \le x$ implies that the region is above $y=0$ (because $y\ge 0$) and below $y=x$ (because $y\le x$). And then the circle bounds from the third side. Similar logic works in the second case. So practice makes perfect.

Comment: thanks for the really clear explanation!! really help me to understand the concept!!

Comment: You are welcome. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

With polar coordinates we get

$\iint_D \ln(x^2 + y^2)dxdy= \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_2^3\ln (r^2)r dr d \theta=4 \pi \int_2^3 r\ln (r) dr$.